# Multi page html layout that works on Chrome 58

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, emacs

I am trying to create a html page, that can be read on screen as well as printed on paper. The layout of the page is a bit advanced and uses e.g. `flex`.

I searched and tried several suggestions (`page-break`*, block sizing, ...) but could not get any useful breaking behavior working on Chrome 58.

Thus I am now asking here how to do a multi page html layout, where I can control which content will be shown on which page (preferably without having to restructure all content)? Target is current Chrome 58.

Bonus points if you post a fiddle that demonstates the structure.

---

**EDIT**:

I am using Emacs and impatient-mode to edit/show the html page.

Comment: Any existing code?

Comment: Simply change the display flex to block inside print styles. Also, [this kind](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks) of page break works everywhere.

Comment: You are asking for opinion and a tutorial, both of which are off topic for SO and I'm surprised by your rep count that you don't know this.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually Emacs `httpd` and `impatient-mode`. Using these breaks some parts of CSS Media queries. Turns out the HTML code worked all along on its own.